# Acrobat C Struct to Delphi Record

Tags: delphi

I'm attempting to utilize Adobe Acrobat OLE to optimize and compress PDFs that we take in through various internal programs.  Adobe uses C for all of their documentation, and I'm having trouble converting a structure to a record in Delphi.

Referencing the SDK [here](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/acrobat_pdfl_api_reference.pdf):

Adobe struct:

```cpp
struct _t_PDFOptParams{
    ASSize_t size;
    ASPathName asPathDest;
    ASFileSys fileSys;
    ProgressMonitor progMon;
    void* progMonClientData;
    PDFOptPDFVersion enmAcrobatVersion;
    PDFOptImageOptionsRec imageOptionsColor;
    PDFOptImageOptionsRec imageOptionsGrayscale;
    PDFOptImageOptionsRec imageOptionsMonochrome;
    PDFont* arrPDFontsToUnembed;
    ASInt32 cPDFontsToUnembed;
    PDFOptFlattenTransparencyOptions pdfOptFlattenTransparencyOptions;
    ASBool bRemoveFormActions;
    ASBool bFlattenFormFields;
    ASBool bRemoveJavascriptActions;
    ASBool bRemoveAlternateImages;
    ASBool bRemoveThumbnails;
    ASBool bRemoveDocumentTags;
    ASBool bSmoothenLines;
    ASBool bMergeImageFragments;
    ASBool bRemovePrintSettings;
    ASBool bRemoveSrchIndex;
    ASBool bRemoveBookmarks;
    ASBool bRemoveCommentsAndWidgets;
    ASBool bRemoveDocInfoAndMetadata;
    ASBool bRemoveObjectData;
    ASBool bRemoveFileAttachments;
    ASBool bRemoveCrossRefs;
    ASBool bRemovePrivateData;
    ASBool bFlattenVisibleLayers;
    PDFOptObjectCompression enmObjectCompression;
    ASBool bUnencodedToFlate;
    ASBool bLZWToFlate;
    ASBool bRemoveInvalidBookmarks;
    ASBool bRemoveInvalidLinks;
    ASBool bRemoveUnreferencedNamedDests;
    ASBool bLinearize;
}PDFOptParamsRec, *PDFOptParams;
```

My attempt in Delphi to create a record:

```pascal
 type PDFParams = record
  size                      : byte;
  asPathDest                : string;
  //fileSys                 : ;
  //progMon                 : null
  //progMonClientData       : null
  //enmAcrobatVersion         : PDFOptPDFVersion;
  //imageOptionsColor
  //imageOptionsGrayscale
  //imageOptionsMonochrome
  //arrPDFontsToUnembed
  cPDFontsToUnembed         :Integer;
  //pdfOptFlattenTransparencyOptions
  bRemoveFormactions        : bool;
  bFlattenFormFields        : bool;
  bRemoveJavascriptActions : bool;
  bRemoveAlternateImages   : bool;
  bRemoveThumbnails        : bool;
  bRemoveDocumentTags      : bool;
  bSmoothenLines           : bool;
  bMergeImageFragments     : bool;
  bRemovePrintSettings     : bool;
  bRemoveSrchIndex         : bool;
  bRemoveBookmarks         : bool;
  bRemoveCommentsAndWidgets: bool;
  bRemoveDocInfoAndMetadata: bool;
  bRemoveObjectData        : bool;
  bRemoveFileAttachments   : bool;
  bRemoveCrossRefs         : bool;
  bRemovePrivateData       : bool;
  bFlattenVisibleLayers    : bool;
  //enmObjectCompression     : bool;
  bUnencodedToFlate        : bool;
  bLZWToFlate              : bool;
  bRemoveInvalidBookmarks  : bool;
  bRemoveInvalidLinks      : bool;
  bRemoveUnreferencedNamedDests  : bool;
  bLinearize               : bool;
end;
```

I'm not sure what I should be setting the commented out fields to?

Comment: Problem is that we can't see the definition of types like ASBool or ASPathName, so we can only guess. But one thing is 100% certain: **none of these C types translates to Delphi's string type.** Please show the defintions of the relevant types and we'll be able to tell you what is right and what is wrong. In the meantime, you can start reading my article: [Pitfals of converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html).

Comment: FWIW. **null** (Null is a constant for a null Variant) **is most definitely wrong too**. Just do `ProgMon: ProgressMonitor;`. or something like it. Again: show us the relevant definitions.

Comment: The docs do not really explain what e.g. an ASFileSys is. I *assume* it is some kind of struct, or even an interface, but unless we see the definition, it is hard to tell. So I *guess* you can simply write: `fileSys: ASFileSys`, juts like you can declare all the AsBool types as such (e.g. `bRemoveBookmarks: ASBool;`). If possible, stay as close to the original as you can, so do not start to "overtranslate". Just make sure the types you are using are well translated too. But again, without definitions of the types used, no one can help you. It makes no sense to guess.

Comment: FWIW, I hate entries like `PDFOptFlattenTransparencyOptions pdfOptFlattenTransparencyOptions;` where type and field name only differ in case. Rather give the type a T in front (in your Delphi translation) to remove any ambiguity, even if the compiler can probably handle the original names too (it can often distinguish between identical type and field names).

Comment: And in C, a `size_t` is usually a Cardinal. Using the wrong type will cause bad alignment, so be sure to look what ASSize_t really is.

Comment: @Remy: does this `<!-- language:delphi -->` trick always work? Is that new?

Comment: @Remy: never mind. Found https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Rudy No, `size_t` is pointer sized

Comment: @David: yes, so a NativeUInt, not always a Cardinal.

Answer (score 1):

What you have translated so far is not even close to being accurate.  `ASSize_t` is not a single `byte`, `ASPathName` is not a `string`, `ASBool` is not a `bool`, etc.

The `PDFOptParams` struct has dependencies on a LOT of other types.  Based on the PDF, the definitions of those types would look something like this:

```pascal
type
  { define this manually only if your Delphi version does not already provide it }
  size_t = NativeUInt;

  ASSize_t = size_t;

  ASInt32 = Int32;
  ASUns16 = UInt16;
  ASBool = ASUns16;

  ASDuration = ASInt32;
  ASFileMode = ASUns16;
  ASMDFile = Pointer;
  ASErrorCode = ASInt32;

  { the following types are not documented in the PDF, so you need
    to track down what they are actually defined as in the SDK and
    translate them as needed... }

  _t_ASPathNameRec = record
    ...
  end;
  ASPathName = ^_t_ASPathNameRec;

  _t_PDFont = record
    ...
  end;
  PDFont = ^_t_PDFont;

  _t_ASTextRec = record
    ...
  end;
  ASText = ^_t_ASTextRec;

  { I'm not going to translate all of the following callback types,
    I'll leave that as an exercise for you to do. I've done the 1st
    two for you (note: the PDF doesn't describe calling conventions
    used, so if 'cdecl' doesn't work, try 'stdcall' instead)... }

  ASFileSysOpenProc = function(pathName: ASPathName; mode: ASFileMode; var fP: ASMDFile): ASErrorCode; cdecl;
  ASFileSysCloseProc = function(f: ASMDFile): ASErrorCode; cdecl;
  ASFileSysFlushProc = ...;
  ASFileSysSetPosProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetPosProc = ...;
  ASFileSysSetEofProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetEofProc = ...;
  ASFileSysReadProc = ...;
  ASFileSysWriteProc = ...;
  ASFileSysRemoveProc = ...;
  ASFileSysRenameProc = ...;
  ASFileSysIsSameFileProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetNameProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetTempPathNameProc = ...;
  ASFileSysCopyPathNameProc = ...;
  ASFileSysDiPathFromPathProc = ...;
  ASFileSysPathFromDIPathProc = ...;
  ASFileSysDisposePathNameProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetFileSysNameProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetStorageFreeSpaceProc = ...;
  ASFileSysFlushVolumeProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetFileFlags = ...;
  ASFileSysAsyncReadProc = ...;
  ASFileSysAsyncWriteProc = ...;
  ASFileSysAsyncAbortProc = ...;
  ASFileSysYieldProc = ...;
  ASFileSysMReadRequestProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetStatusProc = ...;
  ASFileSysCreatePathNameProc = ...;
  ASFileSysAcquireFileSysPathProc = ...;
  ASFileSysClearOutstandingMReadsProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetItemPropsProc = ...;
  ASFileSysFirstFolderItemProc = ...;
  ASFileSysNextFolderItemProc = ...;
  ASFileSysDestroyFolderIteratorProc = ...;
  ASFileSysSetModeProc = ...;
  ASFileSysURLFromPathProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetParentProc = ...;
  ASFileSysCreateFolderProc = ...;
  ASFileSysRemoveFolderProc = ...;
  ASFileSysDisplayStringFromPathProc = ...;
  ASFileSysSetTypeAndCreatorProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetTypeAndCreatorProc = ...;
  ASFileSysReopenProc = ...;
  ASFileSysHardFlushProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetPlatformThingProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetItemPropsAsCabProc = ...;
  ASFileSysCanPerformOpOnItemProc = ...;
  ASFileSysPerformOpOnItemProc = ...;
  ASFileSysAcquirePlatformPathProc = ...;
  ASFileSysReleasePlatformPathProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetNameAsASTextProc = ...;
  ASFileSysDisplayASTextFromPathProc = ...;
  ASFileSysRangeArrivedProc = ...;
  ASFileSysCanSetEofProc = ...;
  ASFileSysDIPathFromPathExProc = ...;
  ASFileSysPathFromDIPathExProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetFilePositionLimitProc = ...;
  ASFileSysOpen64Proc = ...;
  ASFileSysSetPos64Proc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetPos64Proc = ...;
  ASFileSysSetEof64Proc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetEof64Proc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetNameForDisplayProc = ...;
  ASFileSysGetStorageFreeSpace64Proc = ...;

  _t_ASFileSysRec = record
    size: ASSize_t;
    open: ASFileSysOpenProc;
    close: ASFileSysCloseProc;
    flush: ASFileSysFlushProc;
    setpos: ASFileSysSetPosProc;
    getpos: ASFileSysGetPosProc;
    seteof: ASFileSysSetEofProc;
    geteof: ASFileSysGetEofProc;
    read: ASFileSysReadProc;
    write: ASFileSysWriteProc;
    remove: ASFileSysRemoveProc;
    rename: ASFileSysRenameProc;
    isSameFile: ASFileSysIsSameFileProc;
    getName: ASFileSysGetNameProc;
    getTempPathName: ASFileSysGetTempPathNameProc;
    copyPathName: ASFileSysCopyPathNameProc;
    diPathFromPath: ASFileSysDiPathFromPathProc;
    pathFromDIPath: ASFileSysPathFromDIPathProc;
    disposePathName: ASFileSysDisposePathNameProc;
    getFileSysName: ASFileSysGetFileSysNameProc;
    getStorageFreeSpace: ASFileSysGetStorageFreeSpaceProc;
    flushVolume: ASFileSysFlushVolumeProc;
    getFileFlags: ASFileSysGetFileFlags;
    readAsync: ASFileSysAsyncReadProc;
    writeAsync: ASFileSysAsyncWriteProc;
    abortAsync: ASFileSysAsyncAbortProc;
    yield: ASFileSysYieldProc;
    mreadRequest: ASFileSysMReadRequestProc ;
    getStatus: ASFileSysGetStatusProc;
    createPathName: ASFileSysCreatePathNameProc;
    acquireFileSysPath: ASFileSysAcquireFileSysPathProc;
    clearOutstandingMReads: ASFileSysClearOutstandingMReadsProc;
    getItemProps: ASFileSysGetItemPropsProc;
    firstFolderItem: ASFileSysFirstFolderItemProc;
    nextFolderItem: ASFileSysNextFolderItemProc;
    destroyFolderIterator: ASFileSysDestroyFolderIteratorProc;
    setFileMode: ASFileSysSetModeProc;
    urlFromPath: ASFileSysURLFromPathProc;
    getParent: ASFileSysGetParentProc;
    createFolder: ASFileSysCreateFolderProc;
    removeFolder: ASFileSysRemoveFolderProc;
    displayStringFromPath: ASFileSysDisplayStringFromPathProc;
    setTypeAndCreator: ASFileSysSetTypeAndCreatorProc;
    getTypeAndCreator: ASFileSysGetTypeAndCreatorProc;
    reopen: ASFileSysReopenProc;
    hardFlush: ASFileSysHardFlushProc;
    getPlatformThing: ASFileSysGetPlatformThingProc;
    getItemPropsAsCab: ASFileSysGetItemPropsAsCabProc;
    canPerformOpOnItem: ASFileSysCanPerformOpOnItemProc;
    performOpOnItem: ASFileSysPerformOpOnItemProc;
    acquirePlatformPath: ASFileSysAcquirePlatformPathProc;
    releasePlatformPath: ASFileSysReleasePlatformPathProc;
    getNameAsASText: ASFileSysGetNameAsASTextProc;
    displayASTextFromPath: ASFileSysDisplayASTextFromPathProc;
    rangeArrived: ASFileSysRangeArrivedProc;
    canSetEof: ASFileSysCanSetEofProc;
    diPathFromPathEx: ASFileSysDIPathFromPathExProc;
    pathFromDIPathEx: ASFileSysPathFromDIPathExProc;
    getfileposlimit: ASFileSysGetFilePositionLimitProc;
    open64: ASFileSysOpen64Proc;
    setpos64: ASFileSysSetPos64Proc;
    getpos64: ASFileSysGetPos64Proc;
    seteof64: ASFileSysSetEof64Proc;
    geteof64: ASFileSysGetEof64Proc;
    getNameForDisplay: ASFileSysGetNameForDisplayProc;
    getStorageFreeSpace64: ASFileSysGetStorageFreeSpace64Proc;
  end;
  ASFileSysRec = _t_ASFileSysRec;
  ASFileSys = ^_t_ASFileSysRec;

  PMBeginOperationProc = procedure(clientData: Pointer); cdecl;
  PMEndOperationProc = procedure(clientData: Pointer); cdecl;
  PMSetDurationProc = procedure(duration: ASDuration; clientData: Pointer); cdecl;
  PMSetCurrValueProc = procedure(currValue: ASDuration; clientData: Pointer); cdecl;
  PMGetDurationProc = function(clientData: Pointer): ASDuration; cdecl;
  PMGetCurrValueProc = function(clientData: Pointer): ASDuration;
  PMSetTextProc = procedure(text: ASText; clientData: Pointer); cdecl;

  _t_ProgressMonitor = record
    size: ASSize_t;
    beginOperation: PMBeginOperationProc;
    endOperation: PMEndOperationProc;
    setDuration: PMSetDurationProc;
    setCurrValue: PMSetCurrValueProc;
    getDuration: PMGetDurationProc;
    getCurrValue: PMGetCurrValueProc;
    setText: PMSetTextProc;
  end;
  ASProgressMonitorRec = _t_ProgressMonitor;
  ASProgressMonitor = ^_t_ProgressMonitor;
  ProgressMonitor = ASProgressMonitor;

  PDFOptPDFVersion = (kPDFOptRetainVersion = 0, kPDFOptAcrobat4, kPDFOptAcrobat5, kPDFOptAcrobat6, kPDFOptAcrobat7, kPDFOptAcrobat8);
  PDFOptDownsamplingAlgo = (kPDFOptNoDownsampling = 0, kPDFOptAverage, kPDFOptSubsampling, kPDFOptBicubic);
  PDFOptCompressionAlgo = (kPDFOptNoRecompression = 0, kPDFOptJpeg2000, kPDFOptJpeg, kPDFOptFlate, kPDFOptJBIG2, kPDFOptCCITT3, kPDFOptCCITT4, kPDFOptRunLengh);
  PDFOptCompressionQlty = (kPDFOptMinimumQlty = 0, kPDFOptLowQlty, kPDFOptMediumQlty, kPDFOptHighQlty, kPDFOptMaximumQlty, kPDFOptLossless);

  _t_PDFOptImageOptions = record
    size: ASSize_t;
    enmDownsamplingAlgo: PDFOptDownsamplingAlgo;
    ppiDownsampleTo: ASInt32;
    ppiDownsampleAbove: ASInt32;
    enmCompressionAlgo: PDFOptCompressionAlgo;
    enmCompressionQlty: PDFOptCompressionQlty;
    nTileSize: ASInt32;
  end;
  PDFOptImageOptionsRec = _t_PDFOptImageOptions;
  PDFOptImageOptions = ^_t_PDFOptImageOptions;

  _t_PDFOptFlattenTransparencyOptions = record
    size: ASSize_t;
    pctRasterVectorBalance,
    ppiLineArtAndText,
    ppiGradientAndMesh: ASInt32;
    bConvertText,
    bConvertStrokes,
    bClipComplexRegions,
    bPreserveOverprint: ASBool;
  end;
  PDFOptFlattenTransparencyOptionsRec = _t_PDFOptFlattenTransparencyOptions;
  PDFOptFlattenTransparencyOptions = ^_t_PDFOptFlattenTransparencyOptions;

  PDFOptObjectCompression = (kPDFOptUntouchedCompression = 0, kPDFOptFullCompression, kPDFOptPartialCompression, kPDFOptRemoveCompression);

  _t_PDFOptParams = record
    size: ASSize_t;
    asPathDest: ASPathName;
    fileSys: ASFileSys;
    progMon: ProgressMonitor;
    progMonClientData: Pointer;
    enmAcrobatVersion: PDFOptPDFVersion;
    imageOptionsColor,
    imageOptionsGrayscale,
    imageOptionsMonochrome: PDFOptImageOptionsRec;
    arrPDFontsToUnembed: ^PDFont;
    cPDFontsToUnembed: ASInt32;
    pdfOptFlattenTransparencyOptions: PDFOptFlattenTransparencyOptions;
    bRemoveFormActions,
    bFlattenFormFields,
    bRemoveJavascriptActions,
    bRemoveAlternateImages,
    bRemoveThumbnails,
    bRemoveDocumentTags,
    bSmoothenLines,
    bMergeImageFragments,
    bRemovePrintSettings,
    bRemoveSrchIndex,
    bRemoveBookmarks,
    bRemoveCommentsAndWidgets,
    bRemoveDocInfoAndMetadata,
    bRemoveObjectData,
    bRemoveFileAttachments,
    bRemoveCrossRefs,
    bRemovePrivateData,
    bFlattenVisibleLayers: ASBool;
    enmObjectCompression: PDFOptObjectCompression;
    bUnencodedToFlate,
    bLZWToFlate,
    bRemoveInvalidBookmarks,
    bRemoveInvalidLinks,
    bRemoveUnreferencedNamedDests,
    bLinearize: ASBool;
  end;
  PDFOptParamsRec = _t_PDFOptParams;
  PDFOptParams = ^_t_PDFOptParams;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This gives me a lot  to work on, and sets me on the right direction.